# Calling solrj from Solr DIH custom tranformer - dependencies

Tags: solr, jar, solrj

I'm developing DIH custom tranformer, which asks different Solr core and - depending on answer - prepare data. Without querying Solr DIH and custom transformer work as supposed (so it is no problem with any other part of code).

The issue is in the last line of code:

```
HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);  
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("Id:"+id);  
query.setRows(1);  


QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
```

It returns:

```
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper$ReflectionTransformer.transformRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:149)
... 36 more  
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Unhandled exception type SolrServerException  
Unhandled exception type IOException
```

I've checked code from stand-alone application and I had the same problem - I found that I need to add such packages to my Build path:

- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- httpclient-4.5.1.jar
- httpcore-4.4.3.jar
- httpmime-4.5.1.jar
- noggit-0.5.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar

after doing that I was able to communicate with Solr from java (inside Eclipse).
But I have no idea how to say to Solr to use that packages.

I tried to copy them to lib folder and load them by adding

```
<lib dir="./lib" />
```

into solrconfig, but without any success.

I use Solr 5.2.1, Eclipse as IDE and I'm unfortunatelly totally newbie in java (I'm .NET programmer).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I should have used Maven to manage dependiences and build jar (not Eclipse "Build" option).